# What is the best way to redirect all urls which don't start with prefix to given prefix

Tags: nginx

I would like to get redirected all the urls which **do not** start with prefix `/abcd/` to -> `/abcd/` considering that the server uses `proxy_pass`.

```
server {
        location / {

                proxy_pass http://upstream-server/;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

                if ($request_uri = "/"){
                        return 301 /abcd/;
                }
        }
}
```

I am thinking of using regex and negation something like this:

```
location ~ ^/(?!abcd.*).*$ {
          return 301 /abcd/;
}
```

Is there any other/better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that's more complex than you need. Nginx [evaluates](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-nginx-server-and-location-block-selection-algorithms) the most specific block down to the least specific.

In this example anything matching /abcd goes to the proxy_pass block, everything else goes to the / block which is redirected.

I haven't tested this, give it a shot and if it doesn't work I can think some more.

```
location /abcd {
     proxy_pass (etc);
}

location / {
      return 301 /abcd/;
}
```